# Trust certificates in dotnet restore within Macos

Tags: .net, .net-core, nuget

I'm trying to execute a `dotnet restore` but without success. The nuget.config in root directory of my project points to my company artifactory and has some certificates that should be trusted by me.

This is the error:

```
  The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
    The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
```

I have the ca.crt file to trust but I tried a lot of things to trust on it in my mac, but without success:

1. Using `brew info openssl` to see where is the certs folder. Added the ca.cert under   `/usr/local/etc/openssl@3/certs` and executed `/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/bin/c_rehash`.
2. Added ca.crt in `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates` folder.
3. Append ca.crt in `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/cacert.pem`.
4. Added ca.cert under `/etc/ssl/certs` folder.
5. Added in KeyChain App.

Unhappy, nothing worked. Any tips ?